# PHP Script watchdog timer

Tags: php, web-services, timer, watchdog, chunking

To the community,
I am currently writing a PHP script to serve out files using the standard chunk as such:

```
set_time_limit(0);
ob_clean();
ob_start();
while (SoapService->nextChunk()) {
     $chunk=SoapService->chunk();
     print $chunk;
     ob_flush();
     flush();
}
```

What I'd like to do is add some sort of method after the flush() like timerReset();
Then in some sort of timer loop:

```
while (True) {
   Sleep(0.30);
   if (timerCheckandIncrement() > 100) {
      SoapService->notifyClose();
      exit(0);
      /*  or  */
      SoapService->takeSomeAction();
   }
}
```

This way, if the far end were to stop receiving packets and/or were to become unable to keep up with the stream, I would be able to do things like:
a)  Change the encoding bitrate.
b)  Stop the script and clean-up/free-up resources.

I am aware that Apache / PHP can negotiate headers such as Keep-Alive, etc, but I don't know how to exactly leverage them, and/or really make use of them.
Using an AJAX service would not be preferable.  The objective here is streaming media content from a file server to a mobile device over the internet using an application server.  I have considered writing an "app" as well, but cross-platform coding (android/bb/iOS/W7M) as well as my extremely limited knowledge of SmallTalk (ObjectiveC) would add needless complication.